# Python : getting error: TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Tags: python

```
from sys import exit
def gold_room():
    print ("how much gold you need)")
    amount = int(input("amount:"))
    if 0 in amount or  1 in amount:
        print(amount)
gold_room()
```

Output

```
how much gold you need)
amount:1
 line 8, in gold_room
    if 0 in amount or  1 in amount:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: because you're trying to iterate over an integer, which doesn't work

Comment: What is `0 in amount` supposed to mean?

Comment: It's unclear from your question what you want. `if 0 in amount or 1 in amount` is clearly wrong. Do you want to check if the `amount` is equal to either `0` or `1`? In that case, write `if amount == 0 or amount ==1:`

Comment: The `in` operator checks the existence of a value inside an iterable such as a string or list. `amount` is not an iterable, it's an integer

Answer (score 0):

As the others mentioned, it's not clear what you're trying to do. If you want to print `amount` if it is equal to 1 or 0, you can use this

```
from sys import exit
def gold_room():
    print ("how much gold you need)")
    amount = int(input("amount:"))
    if 0 == amount or  1 == amount:
        print(amount)
gold_room()
```

or if you want to print the amount if there is a 1 or 0 in the number (i.e. 123, 220), you can use this

```
from sys import exit
def gold_room():
    print ("how much gold you need)")
    amount = input("amount:")
    if '0' in amount or  '1' in amount:
        print(amount)
gold_room()
```

Comment: Although unknown, the second logic/argument of `123`, `220` etc. doesn't make any sense ;)

Comment: yea i don't know why he would want that, but whatevs

Comment: Hi All, it is just a sample code wherein I am trying to input 0 or 1 and trying to get to the print statement. I think i got the answer I was looking for from Li357. Thanks all for the help

Comment: or `if amount in [0, 1]`